# extension method parameter in gridview databind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm binding an object to a gridview. The object (LeClient) consists of several variables, two of which are related to its phone number. One variable contains a string of digits (LePhone) and the other contains an int that represents the country code (LeCountryCode). I have an extension method for strings that works to format the string LePhone and that I'd like to pass it LeCountryCode as the parameter.

So far, on RowDataBound I have an event handler with the following line:

```
e.Row.Cells[5].Text = (string)(e.Row.Cells[5].Text).ToPhoneFormat(1);
```

I'd like to replace the 1 with the corresponding country code that's stored in the object LeClient associated with the row. How does this work? I tried

```
.ToPhoneFormat(e.Row.DataItem("LeCountryCode"));
```

but it's not giving me the expected result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to cast the DataItem:

```
.ToPhoneFormat((e.Row.DataItem as LeClient).LeCountryCode);
```

Otherwise, you could add a FormattedPhoneNumber property to your LeClient object and bind to that instead.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. How do I access the DataItem of the row?

Comment: ok, you put me on the right track: LeClient ThisClient = e.Row.DataItem as LeClient and then from there I can access the LeCountryCode property of LeClient. Thanks!